Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module error Magento 2.4.6 - Only Chrome browser
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module error on chrome browser,on Mozilla is working fine on magento .2.4.7. How can find the error on production server because error only coming on production server.
Event in chrome incognito browser is working fine.
Assume, issue on required.js file

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi @Community,
Actually I got below error message on each page. But when we enabled on CSP then site is working fine on chrome browser. However, without CSP enable site is working fine on Mozilla browser.
df1fb52….js:168 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(e){"use strict";function r(e,r,n,t){return
o=n.sent(),i=o.fihttps://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
at makeError (df1fb52……744501a1f.js:168:17)
at intakeDefines (df1fb52……44501a1f.js:1254:36)
at df1fb52……44501a1f.js:1452:25
